# Disjointness in definition of sum of linear orders when talking about ordinals

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

A small problem, but I want it to be clear.

I'm reading Jech's *Set Theory* and find the following statement:

> **Lemma 2.24.** For all ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $\alpha+\beta$ and $\alpha\cdot\beta$ are, respectively, isomorphic to the sum and to the product of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

We're interested in the sum here. Before this lemma, the definition of the sum of linear orders is given:

> **Definition 2.22.** Let $(A,<_A)$ and $(B,<_B)$ be disjoint linearly ordered sets. The *sum* of these linear orders is the set $A\cup B$ with the ordering defined as follows: $x<y$ if and only if
> (i) $x,y\in A$ and $x<_A y$, or
> (ii) $x,y\in B$ and $x<_B y$, or
> (iii) $x\in A$ and $y\in B$.

Notice that in this definition the disjointness of the sets is required. So is the definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Sums_of_orders) as well.

But aren't any two ordinals *joint*, since for two arbitrary ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, either $\alpha\subseteq\beta$ or $\beta\subseteq\alpha$? So how can we talk about the sum of two ordinals? Does the lemma use a version of the definition without the disjointness condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That is why we talk about **order type** which is the unique ordinal which is isomorphic to the order defined on $A\cup B$. The ordinal $\alpha+\beta$ is exactly the ordinal isomorphic to the disjoint sum of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Unlike a recursive def'n, in the way I was taught, Lemma 2.24 was practically a definition: $a+b$ is the order-type (o.t.) of the lexicographic (dictionary) order on $(\{0\}\times a)\,\cup\,(\{1\}\times b)$ and $ab$ is the o.t. of the lex.-order on $b\times a$.... BTW, in an exercise in a book by Kunen, I was puzzled by the phrase "in $ot(X)$" until I saw that   $ot(X)$ meant the class of orders that are isomorphic to the ordinal $X$.

Comment: Do you mean "disjoint sum" or "joint sum"? And, how does the concept of the sum of ordinals work? For two ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, suppose $\alpha\leq\beta$, then $\alpha\cup\beta=\beta$, and everything becomes weird. I still can't understand ...

Comment: @Lutalli: I wrote disjoint because I mean disjoint. The sum of $\alpha+\beta$ is ***not*** the ordinal $\alpha\cup\beta$. We take $A=\{0\}\times\alpha$ and $B=\{1\}\times\beta$. Now $A\cap B=\varnothing$, both have a natural well-order on them inherited from $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively, and $\alpha+\beta$ is **the order type** of $A\cup B$ with the well-ordering described in your question. It is the unique ordinal isomorphic to this ***disjoint*** union.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Aha, if $A=\{0\}\times\alpha$ and $B=\{1\}\times\beta$ instead of $A=\alpha$ and $B=\beta$ then it works well. "$\{0\}$" and "$\{1\}$" are like a label giving, and we can actually take $A=\{a\}\times\alpha$ and $B=\{b\}\times\beta$ with arbitrary $a\neq b$. But in the book it's directly written "the sum of $\alpha$ and $\beta$" ... so I got confused.

Comment: @Lutalli: Yes, but $0$ and $1$ have a natural order, which extends to a natural understanding of $\sum_{i\in\alpha}\alpha_i$.